# Lots of undefined references to wxWidgets classes

Tags: c++, linker, wxwidgets

When I compile my wxWidgets project, I get lots of errors stating things similar to:

`undefined reference to _imp___ZN16wxEventHashTableD1EV`

There are more than 50 of these, and it just started happening when I tried to statically link wxwidgets to the exe. I am using wxPack under windows. These errors did not show up when I was dynamically linking wxWidgets. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I suspect the static lib was built with either a different compiler (mingw vs VC++?) or with a different setting 32/64bit or release/debug

Answer (score 0):

The *imp** prefix means you are still pointing the linker to import libraries that go with the dynamic wxWidgets build. (.dll files located in lib/gcc_dll/*)

Make sure you built wxWidgets statically as well and then point the linker to the right location.  The correct files should be under: lib/gcc_lib/*

Comment: In the codeblocks build settings, the search directories are: $(#wx)\lib\gcc_lib\mswu, $(#wx)\lib\gcc_lib, $(#wx)\lib\gcc_lib\mswu for the compiler, linker, and resource compiler respectively. Is there anything I need to change for that build target?